# How to get top 10 user is based on user meta value

Tags: wpdb, user-meta, users

I'm trying to get top 10 users in my wordpress blog based on user meta value.

I've tried few methods & finally able to get just top one user using below wpdb query. But clueless, how we can get top 10 users.

```
$top10alltime = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT MAX( CAST( meta_value AS UNSIGNED ) ) AS top_user FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'alltimeusers'" ); 

echo $top10alltime->top_user;
```

Is `$wpdb` is right for this purpose? Or is there any other solution to get this done? using `WP_User_Query`?

I've tried something with `WP_User_Query`.

```
foreach ( $users as $var => $order ) {
$query->query(
    array(
        'count_total' => false,
        'meta_key' => 'todayuserclicks',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'fields' => 'ID',
        'number' => 10,
        'order' => $order,
    )
);
```

I can't get this done after this .. how can we do this?

Comment: Couldn't this be done with [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)?

Comment: add additional code to your question by [editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/206721/edit) it - thanks

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

By using [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) I meant something along the lines of the following:

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key'     => 'todayuserclicks',
          'compare' => 'EXISTS'
      )
   ),
  'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'      => 'DESC',
  'number'     => '10',
  'fields'     => 'all_with_meta', // does NOT return meta, see below note
);
$todayuserclicks_top_10 = get_users( $args );
```

Note:

Even with the parameter `fields` set to `all_with_meta` no post meta values are included to the result. The documentation for [`WP_User_Query` - Return Fields Parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter) it says to this:

> 'all_with_meta' currently returns the same fields as 'all' which does not include user fields stored in wp_usermeta. You must create a second query to get the user meta fields by ID or use the __get PHP magic method to get the values of these fields.

Comment: I don't have any clue how can we return the meta value and user id's of top 10 users... It's returning an array and how can we get user details? Can you please help?

Comment: Yes, when i've added 'alltimeusers' in the fields parameter, it's not giving me any alltimeusers meta values? 

It's giving me an array like this when i dump it

`array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "8" [4]=> string(1) "6" [5]=> string(1) "7" [6]=> string(1) "2" }`

Comment: I'm not getting all the data with all_with_meta too ... It's not showing info of my custom user meta field.

Comment: Ohh .. Can I have some assistance on getting this? A quick code snippet?

Comment: Yea, did in the same way already :) Thanks, but the results are not in descending order. I don't know why.

Comment: Got the solution, when the meta_value is numeric we should use 'meta_value_num' instead of meta_value. :)

Comment: sometime it is just too easy... :) @Anvy

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do with get_users, something like:

```
$topusers = get_users( array (
    'meta_key'     => 'todayuserclicks',
    'meta_value'   => '',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
    'orderby'      => 'meta_value',
    'order'        => 'DESC',
    'number'       => '10',
) );
```

Comment: How can we get top 10 user ids & meta values with this?

Comment: I assume you want to get the top 10 users with highest value of 'todayuserclicks', is that right? If so, this code will serve you, just do a loop of the $topusers after. You can also do a var_dump($topusers); to check what it returned.

Comment: Yes, But it's not displaying in the descending order. I don't know which way it's showing.